# Could not connect to your Ethereum client

Tags: testrpc

When I type testrpc cmd in console, client is working, then many many "eth_getBlockByNumber" appear,  why ???  please give me some advice.

Then I open other window, type "truffle test"  cmd,  it can not work...

```
D:\www\smartContract\demo3>truffle test

Could not connect to your Ethereum client. Please check that your Ethereum client:
    - is running
    - is accepting RPC connections (i.e., "--rpc" option is used in geth)
    - is accessible over the network
    - is properly configured in your Truffle configuration file (truffle.js)
```

Comment: testrpc  listen default port 8545,    truffle  develop port  is  9545,  I  change  
8545  to 9545   in  truffle-config.js,   but  how can I  change  testrpc port ?

Answer (score 4):

Here the problem is that you don't start your testrpc.
You can start the testrpc in 2 way, one by running **testrpc --account="" --gasPrice 0** or by runnig the geth client with the rpc option as **geth --rpc**.
Also make sure that you configured your truffle.js file properly to accept the connection from 8545 port.

You can even use aurora as a client. In this case you should give the user and password combination with the rpc endpoint of the node in the web3 pack. You can find more about this in [the official doc](http://control-stage.photic.io/docs/docs/truffle/)

Answer (score 2):

`truffle develop` should be executed before deploying any contract.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: Change truffle.js code as below or as per testrpc listening port.
 Change host number and port accordingly as sample below

> module.exports = {
>     networks: {
>       development: {
>         host: 'localhost',
>         port: 8545,
>         network_id: '*' // Match any network id
>       }
>     }
>   }

Answer2:
Use below command line to change test rpc port to specific.
Command Line:

> $ testrpc < options >
>   -p or --port: Port number to listen on. Defaults to 8545.
>   -h or --hostname: Hostname to listen on. Defaults to Node's server.listen() default.

Answer (score 0):

Check the parameters of your Ethereum client by:

Confirming whether the port displayed in your terminal is similar to the one in the "truffle-config.js" file. 
The 2 port numbers should be identical.

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally I had to open port 8545 to localhost:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s localhost --dport 8545 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

After running the Ethereum development server look in which port it is running.[image]

And the change in truffle-config.js as follows
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open Ganache and check `RPC SERVER HTTP://127.0.0.1:7545`

Open `truffle-config.js`

Now change this `truffle-config.js` according to the above port no

```
// development: {
    //  host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
    //  port: **7545**,            // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
    //  network_id: "*",       // Any network (default: none)
    // },
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Image of Invalid json rpc]

To solve this problem, go to truffle-config.js then change localhost to 127.0.0.1

[image: truffle-config]

Answer (score -1):

Truffle is not working because you have to install Truffle and then you can test

Before installing truffle you have to install `npm`

Installing npm

```
$ install npm
```

Installing truffle

```
$ npm install truffle
```

Even if the problem is not solvable, then this is example :

https://medium.com/etherereum-salon/eth-testing-472c2f73b4c3

https://www.npmjs.com/package/truffle/tutorial

Please Try it

Thank you!

Comment: "truffle init" can  work,  other  cmd (truffle  compile/test/server...) can not  work,

Comment: Please all cmd close Then truffle init

Comment: I recreate  an empty folder demo7，  then I type "trufflle init",  it is ok, but truffle test/compile/...  cmds still can not work,  so strange...